# How do I write asinh in terms of $\log$?

Tags: quadratics, inverse-function, hyperbolic-functions

I've found in multiple places (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions)) that

$$ \sinh^{-1} x = \log\left[x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}\right] $$

Wikipedia says this can be derived via the quadratic formula. Can anyone explain how I would go about this derivation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Gibbs, we set

$$ y = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2} $$

and let $z = e^x$. We then can write

$$ y = \frac{z - \frac{1}{z}}{2} $$

$$ 2yz = z^2 - 1 $$

$$ z^2 - 2yz - 1 = 0 $$

Using the quadratic formula, we may then find $z$ in terms of $y$:

$$ z = \frac{2y \pm \sqrt{4y^2 + 4}}{2} $$

$$ z = y \pm \sqrt{y^2 + 1} $$

Replacing our definitions of $y$ and $z$, we will have

$$ e^x = \sinh x \pm \sqrt{\sinh^2 x + 1} $$

If we let $x = \sinh^{-1} u$, we will then have

$$ \sinh^{-1} u = \log\left[u + \sqrt{u^2 + 1}\right] $$

where we've dropped the possibility of subtraction with in the $\log$ because the argument to $\log$ must be positive.

Comment: The argument is correct.

Answer (score 2):

By definition $$\sinh(x) = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}.$$
Set
$$y=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$
and try to find $x$. Can you do it?

Comment: Aha! I figured it out. Answer pending...

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = \sinh^{-1}(x)$.  Then, by definition of inverse function:

$$\sinh{y} = x$$
$$\frac{e^{y} - e^{-y}}{2} = x$$
$$e^{y} - e^{-y} = 2x$$

Let $u = e^y$.  Then:

$$u - \frac{1}{u} = 2x$$
$$u^2 - 1 = 2xu$$
$$u^2 - 2xu - 1 = 0$$

This is a quadratic in terms of $u$, with $a = 1$, $b = -2x$, and $c = -1$.  Plugging these numbers into the formula gives:

$$u = \frac{2x \pm \sqrt{4x^2 + 4}}{2}$$
$$u = x \pm \sqrt{x^2 + 1}$$
$$e^y = x \pm \sqrt{x^2 + 1}$$
$$y = \log\left(x \pm \sqrt{x^2 + 1}\right)$$

But note that using the $-$ root from the formula would have us taking the log of a negative number, which does not produce a real number.  So we choose the $+$ root instead.

$$y = \log\left(x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}\right)$$

QED

Comment: Your derivation is much cleaner than mine.